# Change the text of label from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, timer

so my first problem is what happen when we click the button? page refresh or something else, because i'm working on a small project and facing a problem

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var totalTime = 0;
    var interval = 0;
    var min = 0;
    var hr = 0;
    var sec = 0;
    var secstr = 0;
    var minstr = 0;
    var flag = 0;
    window.onload = startResetTimer

    function startResetTimer() {
        totalTime = 20;
        hr = Math.floor(totalTime / 3600);
        sec = totalTime % 60;
        if (sec == 0)
            min = (totalTime / 60) % 60;
        flag = 1;
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            if (flag == 1) {
                if (totalTime <= 0) {
                    flag = 0;
                    PageMethods.CallIt();
                }
                else {
                    totalTime--;
                    hr = Math.floor(totalTime / 3600)
                    sec = totalTime % 60
                    if (sec == 0)
                        min = (totalTime / 60) % 60
                    if (sec < 10)
                        secstr = "0" + sec
                    else
                        secstr = sec
                    if (min < 10)
                        minstr = "0" + min
                    else
                        minstr = min
                }
            }
            console.log(document.getElementById('MainContent_Label2'));
            document.getElementById('MainContent_Label2').innerHTML = "" + hr + ":" + minstr + ":" + secstr
        }, 1000)
    }

</script>
```

this is timer code and when timer expire i'm calling page method "CallIt()" //just debug name//
//asp.net code

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static _Default obj;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        obj = this;
    }
    public void print()
    {
        Label1.Text = "called form every where";
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static void CallIt()
    {
        obj.print();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        obj.print();
    }
}
```

now from CallIt() i call another function print() which change the text of "Label1" and calling the same function print() from button click, now when i press button it change the text of Label1 but when the timer expire it doesn't, the print() function i s called i check this by using breakpoints but it doesn't reflect in the page.So i thought page refresh should help so i place

```
if(totalTime <= 0) {
   PageMethods.CallIt();
   window.location.reload() ;
}
```

but this restart the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the web method of asp.net page from javascript, the MS javasvript engine do the ajax request to that page and return to javascript the data which was provided by the service call and that's it. Your CallIt method returns nothing so in javascript you will receive nothing, and as I said anything else will not be evaluated, also please do not store "this" in the static property, 'cause the Page object recreates each time during each request and you can get something slightly wrong in it in multi-client environment.

So I would recommend you to call this method from you javascript, collect the data that method returns and manually update the label using javascript in the browser

Comment: hey is there any other solution for "this"? because i can't make all datatype static and using inside the static function and i also can't access the label inside the static function.

Comment: What actually you want to do? Please share more context of your issue.

Comment: actually i'm working on a online examination site, for storing question i'm using xml and load paper dynamically from xml using lable and radiobuttonlist. Now when user submit the paper i want to highlight the correct answer if he/she chooses wrong, this is done using c# all the answer check and highlighting but there is timer when it expire it show the same effect as submit button, i call the page method from js, function is called but no effect shown on the page!